# Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object PDO

Tags: php

I made the rookie mistake of starting my project in windows and migrating it to Ubuntu.This move was forced upon me and resulted in a lot of unintended consequences. It generated a lot of errors one being fatal.

I know that the object is not null by simply doing a var_dump. Inside the var_dump the method is there. So my question: Why would this work flawlessly in a Windows environment and not in the linux environment? I went through the code and fixed all my capitalization issues I think.

The code that generates the error is:

```
public function find($user = null) {
    if ($user) {
        $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
        $data = $this->_db->get('user', array($field, '=', $user));
        var_dump($data);
        if ($data->count()) {
            $this->_data = $data->first();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The contents is

```
object(DB)#3 (6) { ["_pdo":"DB":private]=> object(PDO)#4 (0) { } ["_query":"DB":private]=> object(PDOStatement)#5 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(31) "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?" } ["_error":"DB":private]=> bool(false) ["_result":"DB":private]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (8) { ["id"]=> string(2) "39" ["username"]=> string(8) "test1234" ["password"]=> string(64) "d1dcebd95402062c466eeb1e2b5e6c3b217a0fe160bc3baac86bafc9613494e9" ["salt"]=> string(32) ".JMs.ˆ~ìdÿ)7Ð §FKS¨Ê×$'å¹Yˆc¥" ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["joined"]=> string(10) "2014-11-20" ["disabled"]=> string(1) "0" ["email"]=> string(18) "jt125845@gmail.com" } } ["_count":"DB":private]=> int(1) ["error"]=> bool(false) } 

        return false;
    }
```

Again, this is my first project.

Comment: Different php versions?

Comment: Check that `$data` variable is written using the same charset encoding (or just copy it from the line above to the place with `count()`). Or retype it. PHP allows mixing encodings in variable names (like letter `a` from ASCII and any other unicode set) and creates another variable.

Comment: I am sorry. I am bit lost on this explanation. Can you please elaborate a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: What does `var_dump($data)` show? Also, what's DB? What library are you using?

Answer (score -1):

I would convert the result into an array first and then call the standard `count`:

```
public function find($user = null) {
    if ($user) {
        $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';

        $result = $this->_db->get('user', array($field, '=', $user));
        $data = $result->result_array();
        var_dump($data);
        if (count($data) > 0) {
            $this->_data = $data[0];
            return true;
        }
}
```

As about the cause of the problem: There might be differences between the versions. It is not a problem you have switched operating systems, it is good for learning.

EDIT:

Apparently my previous idea was not sufficient, at least in the environment where it should work. I have no possibilities to test it now, so my new idea might be wrong as well. I will share it though, hoping for the best:

```
public function find($user = null) {
    if ($user) {
        $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';

        $statement = $this->_db->prepare("select * from user where ".$field." = :userValue");
        $statement->execute(array(':userValue' => $user));
        if ($data = $statement->fetch()) {
            $this->_data = $data;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I eagerly tried your suggestion and got an error.   Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB::result_array()

Comment: @o6t9o, thank you for your observations, I have edited my answer. I have kept the initial version which was marked as incorrect in your comment and under the edit I have shared my newest idea.

Comment: @o6t9o What you've said makes is paradoxical; first you get an error about trying to call a method on something that's not an object and with this code you get "undefined method" implying that it *is* an object.